# how to get location on google map using enter longitude and latitude values passed on textbox?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

i try to find location on google map
and i enter place name in textbox and submit button than location find successfully
but how to find location using enter longitude and latitude on textbox?
i tried to pass longitude and latitude values like this -26.958405,24.729860 in textbox but showing location on map not display accurate result.
so how its possible for find location using longitude and latitude value passed on textbox?

```
<input type="text"   id="addressinput" class="form-control col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="view" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyANdsvrNpO6CDr_-Y&callback=initMap"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var geocoder;
    function InitializeMap() {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.833959630595874, 30.35492856055498);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 9,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    }

    function FindLocaiton() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        InitializeMap();

        var address = document.getElementById("addressinput").value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location

                });

            }
            else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });

    }


    function Button1_onclick() {
        FindLocaiton();
    }

    window.onload = InitializeMap;

</script>
```

Comment: first, you're creating a map and a geocoder each time you click the button. You should create only once, and keep a reference to them outside the functions, so you can re-use them.

Comment: Looks accurate to me [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6ep17bxt/); though you don't need the geocoder if you have the coordinates (using the geocoder will move the marker to the closest "known" location)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the lat, lang in myLatLng varYou can use your gecoder this way

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.833959630595874, 30.35492856055498);
google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({'latLng': myLatLng}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  if (results[0]) {
    alert(results[0].formatted_addres);
}
else {
  alert( "Geocoder impossible");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add two different textboxes for longitute and latitude values and pass values on your javascript giolocation

```
var address = document.getElementById("addressinput").value;
var address1 = document.getElementById("addressinput1").value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address },{ 'address1': address1 }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location

                });
```

i understand your question
try this code for find location using longitude and latitude its say reverse mapping

```
 <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div><br/><br/>

 <div id="floating-panel">
 <input id="latlng" type="text" placeholder="Enter map coordinates">
 <input id="submit" type="button" value="view">
 </div>



 <script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
    });
  }

  function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
    var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
    var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
    var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[1]) {
          map.setZoom(11);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
          });
          infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } else {
          window.alert('No results found');
        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YourGoogleMapKEY">
</script>
```